# Задача на теорию игр

Tags: алгоритм

> В начальный момент времени Снарк находится в точке прямой с целой неотрицательной координатой X. За ход он может оказаться в любой точке с целой координатой Y при условии, что |X-Y| <= S. Кроме того, Снарк не любит булочки, поэтому он никогда не прыгнет в клетку, где одна из этих противных штук лежит. Булочник не хочет, чтобы Снарк попал домой. После каждого хода Снарка Булочник может положить булочку в любую точку прямой при условии, что это не начало координат (дом Снарка) и в этой клетке нет Снарка. Определите, сможет ли Булочник помешать Снарку оказаться дома. Изначально в некоторых клетках лежат булочки.
>
> Входные данные
>   В первой строке задаются целые числа 0 <= X < 10000, 0 < S <= 100 и 0 <= N < max(X-1, 0) - количество булочек, которые уже лежат на прямой. Далее идут N различных чисел 0 < bi < X - координаты точек, где лежит гадость.
>
> Выходные данные
>   Выведите "YES", если Булочник сможет реализовать свои грязные планы, "NO" - если при любых действиях врага Снарк сможет припрыгать домой.

Ясно, что задача по теории игр. Подскажите идею решения (готовая программа мне не нужна, так как хочу сам написать).

Comment: В качестве идеи, а не законченного алгоритма: Булочнику надо выстроить ряд из булочек длиной в `S` «левее» Снарка до того, как Снарк окажется дома. Если он сможет такое сделать, то Снарку никак не пробраться. Если не сможет, Снарк на каждом ходу очевидно сможет приблизиться к дому на хотя бы 1.

Comment: @VladD, До этого я тоже дошел. Но проблема в том, что разные расположения уже выложенных булочек могут приводить к тому, что ряд будет выгоднее строить в разных местах, и в этом и есть основная сложность этой задачи.

Comment: @Antony: ... А также расстояние до Снарка. Если выгодная конфигурация расположена около Снарка, можно просто не успеть достроить ряд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Снарк хочет сделать минимальное число шагов, чтобы добраться до цели.

В каждом состоянии можно посчитать, какие конкретно шаги при такой стратегии он сделает. И через сколько шагов он окажется там или сям.

Это число шагов — число булок, которые успеет расставить Булочник.

Двигая «рамку» длиной в S от 1 до Снарка, для каждого ее положения можно посчитать недостающее число ходов для закрытия (построения сплошной преграды).

Сопоставляя недостающее число ходов с тем, как скоро там окажется Снарк, можно найти, или не найти решение.

Вряд ли тут стоит усложнять стратегию до «замедления» Снарка где-то загодя.. Эти же ходы лучше потратить непосредственно на строительство преграды, как мне поверхностно кажется.

Comment: Спасибо. Есть некоторые неточности (существуют расположения, при которых Булочник может создать сплошную преграду с помощью 4 булочек начиная с точки, до которой Снарк доходит за 4 хода), но эта идея очень помогла мне.